# installed visual code and its giving me include error | path/crtdbg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, iostream

so i have installed visual code after trying to learn some basics. i have installed visual studio 2022 before so i have that on my computer. i tried changing the path but im still getting the same error. i have installed vs code on another drive. i was wondering if anyone know how to fix this or whats causing it. i attached a screenshot of terminal to so you can see the error for yourself.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb7V0.png)

Thanks

Comment: Bad news: That ain't Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Good news, OP knows that and is asking why vscode isnt working

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)?

Comment: No I have not also ive started my project in the download folder. Imma read the documentation when I get home